# Webapp to predict whether a StackExchange site is likely to get closed soon

Tags: gratis, web-apps, stack-exchange, analytics, prediction

StackExchange is an always-growing collection of QA sites, new sites are proposed every day at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and they have to go through define, commit, private beta, public beta before becoming a full site. Many get closed during one of these steps, based on informed opinions of a number of StackExchange employees.

Let's say I want to check whether the [Japanese Language QA site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) is likely to get closed soon.

Is there a webapp that allows me to check easily, without having to design models and crunch [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/) by myself?

Requirements:

- Predictions for all sites (any stage)
- Good model using all past data. A single model for all sites is OK, but more detailed models are also OK.
- Sample data is relatively limited for now (70k for proposals, 150 for betas). So indicating a confidence score for each prediction would be great.
- Free
- Data is refreshed regularly
- Ways to interact a bit with the data would be welcome, but not strictly necessary. For instance overlaying the statistics histograms of 2 sites and get the "similitude ratio" for each metric.

Comment: A few months ago I was thinking of doing the same! For closed SE [data dumps are available on Area 51](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234164/178179). That should be a nice ML project :)

Comment: Yeah. And again something for StackApps (please forgive me mentioning that all the time, but being specifically for SE, that's where it should be listed at least ;)

Comment: Given the small sample size, this seems grossly unrealistic.

Comment: @Gilles: Interesting point! I see that 70k sites have been proposed so far, do you know what proportion has made it to beta? Also, why do you often choose words that sound offensive? Let's maintain a good atmosphere on this site :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I understood your question being about bet websites, of which there have been something like 150. If this is about Area 51 proposals, the volume is sufficient for some statistical analysis — but you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: @Gilles: I am indeed talking about beta websites here. Would you mind telling your source for the 150 number? There are currently 123 sites, very few of which existed before Area51... does that mean that only ~25 beta sites have ever been closed? Sounds lower than I would have expected. Anyway, feel free to post an answer detailing why my wish can not be implemented by any software.

Comment: A search for [“has been closed”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+been+closed%22+site:area51.stackexchange.com+-site:discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) turns up 25 results of which 1 is a false positive. I think it's missing the ones that failed and were rebooted, but there are only a handful of those.

Comment: Even if you analyze all proposals, I don't think you'll get a useful result. I strongly suspect that you'll find a very good predictor of launching is making it into beta.